# How to populate the selected value from database in the Edittemplate in the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

'callout_status'Table
[image]

case_detail table

[image]

Now i have a gridview with dropdownlist within it.
Basically the gridview display data from the case_detail table, and the dropdown list display data from the callout_status table.

Currently, i can populate the dropdownlist from database.
For the ItemTemplate, it can show the selected value from database. But i cannot show the selected value in the Edittemplate, every time i press the edit button, the selected option in the db wont show. Any idea how to do it.Many thanks.

aspx page

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" DataKeyNames="id" 
        onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
        onrowdeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" 
        onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" BackColor="White" 
        BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="3" 
        CellSpacing="1" GridLines="None" OnRowDataBound="gvItem_RowDataBound" >
        <Columns>

          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="收方">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3"  runat="server"  ></asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("receiver_status_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField> 
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="寄方">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2"  runat="server"  ></asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("shipper_status_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="case_id">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("case_id") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("case_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>


            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remarks">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("remark") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("remark") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#E7E7FF" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#DEDFDE" ForeColor="Black" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#9471DE" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#594B9C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#33276A" />
    </asp:GridView>

</div>
</form>
```

aspx.cs page

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         string connString = "Server=localhost;Database=cs_case;Uid=root;Pwd='';SslMode=none";

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connString);

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            refreshdata();
        }

    }

    public void refreshdata()
    {
        string connString = "Server=localhost;Database=cs_case;Uid=root;Pwd='';SslMode=none";

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connString);

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select id, remark,case_id,shipper_status_id,receiver_status_id from case_detail", con);
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }

    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        refreshdata();
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        string connString = "Server=localhost;Database=cs_case;Uid=root;Pwd='';SslMode=none";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connString);

        int id = Convert.ToInt16(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["id"].ToString());
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("delete from case_detail where id = @id", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        refreshdata();

    }
    protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        refreshdata();
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        string connString = "Server=localhost;Database=cs_case;Uid=root;Pwd='';SslMode=none";

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connString);


        int id = Convert.ToInt16(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["id"].ToString());
        TextBox txtname = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox2") as TextBox;
        TextBox txtemail = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("TextBox3") as TextBox;
        DropDownList drpgender = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("DropDownList2") as DropDownList;
        DropDownList drpgender2 = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("DropDownList3") as DropDownList;

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("update case_detail set remark=@remark, case_id=@case_id,shipper_status_id=@shipper_status_id,receiver_status_id=@receiver_status_id where id =@id", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remark", txtname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@case_id", txtemail.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shipper_status_id", drpgender.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@receiver_status_id", drpgender2.SelectedItem.Text);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        refreshdata();

        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        refreshdata();


    }
//dropdown
    protected void gvItem_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //1st dopdown
            var DropDownList1 = e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList2") as DropDownList;

            if (DropDownList1 != null)
            {
                var dt = new DataTable();
                using (var con = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=cs_case;Uid=root;Pwd='';SslMode=none"))
                {
                    con.Open();
                   // var cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from callout_status where category ='shipper'", con);

                    var cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from callout_status where category ='shipper'", con);
                    var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }

                DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "status";
                DropDownList1.DataValueField = "status";
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
                DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "NA"));
            }
            //2nd dopdown

            var DropDownList3 = e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList3") as DropDownList;

            if (DropDownList3 != null)
            {
                var dt = new DataTable();
                using (var con = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=cs_case;Uid=root;Pwd='';SslMode=none"))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    var cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from callout_status where category ='receiver'", con);
                    var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }

                DropDownList3.DataSource = dt;
                DropDownList3.DataTextField = "status";
                DropDownList3.DataValueField = "status";
                DropDownList3.DataBind();
                var value = e.Row.DataItem.ToString();

                DataRowView dr = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
                DropDownList3.SelectedValue = value; // you can use e.R


                DropDownList3.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", "NA"));


            }


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check it the row is in edit mode in `gvItem_RowDataBound`.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{

    if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
    {
        //find the items in the edit row
        var DropDownList3 = e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList3") as DropDownList;

        DropDownList3.DataSource = dt;
        DropDownList3.DataTextField = "status";
        DropDownList3.DataValueField = "status";
        DropDownList3.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        //every other row
        var Label2 = e.Row.FindControl("Label2") as Label;

        Label2.Text = "Label 2 found";
    }
}
```

Comment: just getting started to learn the asp.net, do u mean just adding the if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
    {       }can you explain a bit more what's find control

Comment: I've updated my answer. But you are already using it `var DropDownList1 = e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList2") as DropDownList`